# jqPlot Horizontal Bar Graph Point Label Challenge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

New to jqPlot and am struggling with the data and labels for Horizontal charts.

Here is the problem.  My desired chart should look like this:

http://www.ifthen.biz/DesiredChart.png

My actual chart however, looks like this:

http://www.ifthen.biz/ActualChart.png

Cannot seem to get the point labels (in this case Yes and No) to correspond to the data for each question.

Each question has a Yes or No answer.  For each Yes or No I tally the answers so that i can get the desired chart.

Please see the Code below:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var q1 = [20, 58];
            var q2 = [5, 21];
            var plot1 = $.jqplot('quickStatsChart', [q1,q2], {
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    shadowAngle: 60,
                    showMarker: false,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barDirection: 'horizontal'
                    },
                    pointLabels:{
                        show: true,
                        location: 'e',
                        labels: ['Yes','No']
                    }
                },
                axes: {
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ['Question 1', 'Question 2']
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any ideas how I can make this work?

++Tx

Here is the new code that I tried:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // [ tally question 1, tally question 2]
            var sX = [[[2,'q1'], [4,'q2']],  //  Yes'
                      [[5,'q1'], [1,'q2']]]; //  No's
            var plot1 = $.jqplot('quickStatsChart', sX, {
                seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    shadowAngle: 60,
                    showMarker: false,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        barDirection: 'horizontal'
                    },
                    pointLabels:{
                        show: true,
                        location: 'e',
                        labels: ['Yes','No']
                    }
                },
                axes: {
                    yaxis: {
                        renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The outcome is the same as the Actual Chart above.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php) As you can see the second number of the variables is the name of the yaxis

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [
        [[2,1], [4,2], [6,3], [3,4]],
        [[5,1], [1,2], [3,3], [4,4]],
        [[4,1], [7,2], [1,3], [2,4]]], {
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
            shadowAngle: 135,
            rendererOptions: {
                barDirection: 'horizontal'
            }
        },
        axes: {
            yaxis: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Try deleting it is the only difference. If works change q1 with Yes and q2 with No

```
pointLabels:{
    show: true,
    location: 'e',
    labels: ['Yes','No']
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I'm specifically trying to set the pointLabels to Yes or No for each question.  I followed your example but still have the same problem.

Comment: I tried it and it puts the Yes and No labels on the vertical axis, which is what we do not want.

Comment: Yes I am just about ready to pull my hairs. :)  Thanks for your efforts.